# Problem serializing primitive data using WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, xml-serialization, metadata

Scenario: WCF client app, calling a web-service (JAVA) operation, wich requires a complex object as parameter. Already got the metadata.

Problem: The operation has some required fields. One of them is a enum. In the SOAP sent, isnt the field above (generated metadata) - Im using WCF diagnostics and Windows Service Trace Viewer:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="Consult-Filter", Namespace="http://webserviceX.org/")]
public partial class ConsFilter : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private PersonType customerTypeField;
```

Property:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("customer-type", Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=1)]
    public PersonType customerType {
        get {
            return this.customerTypeField;
        }
        set {
            this.customerTypeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("customerType");
        }
    }
```

The enum:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "2.0.50727.3082")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(TypeName="Person-Type", Namespace="http://webserviceX.org/")]
    public enum PersonType {

        /// <remarks/>
        F,

        /// <remarks/>
        J,
    }
```

Operation metadata:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
public partial class consultRequest {

    [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="http://webserviceX.org/", Order=0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(IsNullable=true)]
    public ServiceClient.ConsultServiceReference.ConsFilter filter;

    public consultRequest() {
    }

    public consultRequest(ServiceClient.ConsultServiceReference.ConsFilter filter) {
        this.filter = filter;
    }
}
```

The trace log:

```
    <MessageLogTraceRecord>
<HttpRequest xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/ServiceModel/Management/MessageTrace">
<Method>POST</Method>
<QueryString></QueryString>
<WebHeaders>
<VsDebuggerCausalityData>data</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
</WebHeaders>
</HttpRequest>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header>
<Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none"></Action>
<ActivityId CorrelationId="correlationId" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">activityId</ActivityId>
</s:Header>
<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<filter xmlns="http://webserviceX.org/">
<product-code xmlns="">116</product-code>
<customer-doc xmlns="">777777777</customer-doc>
</filter>
</s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
</MessageLogTraceRecord>
```

Comment: Please show us the operation contract, and any data contracts used by the operation. Also, what's the relationship between `PersonType` and `TipoPessoa` (which I believe is Portuguese for "type of person").

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the object name. Its a JAVA web-service, that I dont have control. I put the operation metadata. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the XML Serializer to serialize primitive types which have `minOccurs="0"` in the XML Schema, there is an additional property added. It is named *Specified. In your case, I expect you have a boolean property named `customerTypeSpecified`. You will need to set it to `true` whenever you need the `customerType` to be sent.

Comment: You did it! I just passed the customerTypeSpecified=true in the obj constructor. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simple question: if you instantiate the object normally and write it out to the console or System.Diagnostics.WriteLine explicitly using XmlSerializer, do you see the same behavior?